# Run macros after re-installed Windows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

A week ago I deleted my windows 10 pro and installed it on my pc again.
Then I installed MS Office 2013 (64-bit) again too.
Unfortunately, I could not work my macros on my pc. It gives run time error 9.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

For i = 17 To 512
For j = 1 To 9
Worksheets("İstekFişi").Cells(i, j).Value = ""
Next j
Next i

Sheets("İstekFişi").Range("P14").Value = Sheets("İstekFişi").Range("P14").Value + 1

MsgBox "The SpreadSheet is clean now!"

Unload Me

End Sub
```

By the way, this macro works well on another pc.
P.S. Before I re-installed windows my macro was working fine on my pc.

Is anyone live the same problem as me? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Have a Nice Day.

Comment: What happened when you tried to run your macro? Please be specific.

Comment: It gives run time error 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
For i = 17 To 512
For j = 1 To 9
Worksheets("İstekFişi").Cells(i, j).Value = ""
Next j
Next i
```

use

```
Worksheets("İstekFişi").Range("A17:I512").Value = vbNullString
```

`Run-time error 9` can also occur if the sheet name you're referencing does not exist, i.e. make sure you haven't renamed your sheet or deleted it by accident on the Windows 10 computer. (Of course this doesn't apply if you can save and copy the file back to the old computer and it works there but not on the new).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable opinions @Miqi180
As I understand I am living a systemically problem.
I could not run any macros that I wrote before I re-installed my windows.

By the way your code did not run too.